# How does head stops cat in following command : cat /dev/urandom | head -c 10

Tags: shell

How does it happen that if I enter:

```
cat /dev/urandom
```

then it will take forever to output data, but with:

```
cat /dev/urandom | head -c 10
```

the output ends after 10 random bytes, does `head` instructs somehow `cat` to finish its output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `cat` will get a `SIGPIPE` signal when it tries to write to a pipe with no readers (when `head` terminates, it automatically closes its stdin, which is also the only open handle to the reading end of the pipe).

If you *somehow* get another handle to the reading end of the pipe, the cat will not finish, but *block* after it fills up the pipe buffer:

(Linux-only example):

```
cat /dev/urandom 3</dev/stdout | head -c 10 > /tmp/junk
<staying there until you ^C>
```

Also, if you get `cat` to *ignore* the `SIGPIPE` signal, the write which would've generated the `SIGPIPE` signal will simply fail, setting the `errno` to `EPIPE` = `Broken pipe` **^1**:

```
{ trap '' PIPE; cat /dev/urandom; } | head -c 10 >/tmp/junk
cat: write error: Broken pipe
```

The `head` process has no hand in all this; it doesn't *signal*, *instructs* or care at all about the `cat`; it just reads whatever it needs and then just exits, leaving it to the operating system to take care of all the rest.

---

**^1** This latter behaviour is (quite annoyingly) the default for python scripts:

```
python -c 'while 1: print("hello")' | head -n2
hello
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```